# What is the potential diff of an infinite resistance wire?

Tags: electric-current, potential, electrical-resistance, voltage

In my opinion it should be 0 as current through it is 0 but it is also 0 in case of 0 resistance wire Is it 0 in both the cases

Comment: Potential difference is not *determined* by current. Rather, current, in an ohmic device like a wire, is determined by the externally produced potential difference and the resistance of the device.

Comment: @BillN, but one could make the argument that it's the other way around (at least in circuit theory).  For example, the voltage across an ideal current source is completely determined by the attached circuit.  If the external circuit is just a resistor, the voltage across *is* determined by the current from the current source and the resistance of the resistor.  I anticipate a counterargument of "but a current source produces just the right voltage across to give the desired current through" but that cuts both ways, i.e., "but a voltage source produces just the right current through to ..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the potential diff of an infinite resistance wire?

In circuit theory, an infinite resistance 'wire' is an ideal open circuit and there is a corresponding notion of an open-circuit voltage $V_{OC}$

Consider, for example, a cell (or battery) that is not connected to an external circuit.  The cell maintains a voltage across its terminals and this voltage is called the open-circuit voltage of the cell.

If one were to place an ideal voltmeter across the cell, the reading would equal $V_{OC}$ since there is no current through an ideal voltmeter just as there is no current through an open circuit.

Then there is the concept of a [Thevenin equivalent circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9venin%27s_theorem#Calculating_the_Th.C3.A9venin_equivalent)

[image]

Note that there is an infinite resistance 'wire' (open circuit) connected between nodes A and B.  There is no current though the open circuit but there is nonetheless a voltage across and this voltage, the open-circuit voltage, is just the Thevenin equivalent voltage $V_{TH}$.

To verify this, place a resistor $R_L$ between the A & B nodes and calculate the voltage across it.  You'll find that the voltage is

$$V_{R_L} = V_{TH}\frac{R_L}{R_{TH} + R_L}$$

Now, take the limit as $R_L\rightarrow\infty$ and find that

$$\lim_{R_L\rightarrow\infty} V_{R_L} = V_{TH}$$

So this is an example of how to find the voltage across an infinite resistance 'wire' since, as you point out, the current through is zero:  replace the 'wire' with a resistor $R$, calculate the voltage across the resistor (leave $R$ as a variable) and take the limit as $R\rightarrow\infty$

Answer (score 0):

My favorite interpretation of ideal wires is as follows: treat a 0-resistance wire as if two components are directly connected, with no wire in between, and treat an infinite-resistance wire as if two components are not connected at all. Therefore, the potential difference across a 0-resistance wire is 0; the two components are directly connected, so there is no change in potential across the connection. In contrast, potential difference across an infinite-resistance wire is indeterminate; since the two components are disconnected, they could be at any voltage in relation to each other.

Comment: The more difficult extreme to wrap your head around - the zero resistance case. With the zero resistance, there is no drop so $V_{high} = V_{low}$. But the current is not zero. It's infinite.

Comment: In that case, since there's no wire, it doesn't make sense to define a current through nothing.

Comment: @docscience Why would the current be infinite in the zero resistance case?

Comment: Actually if the two voltage sources are 'ideal' you still maintain the same voltage drop, and as the resistance approaches zero current goes to infinity. Real sources 'run out' of electrons

Comment: @Phoenix87, it wouldn't be infinite.   For example, connect the terminals of a  current source of current $I$ together with an ideal wire and find that (1) there is no voltage across the wire  and (2) the current through the wire is $I$

Comment: @AlfredCentauri Yes I do get this. Indeed the equation $0 = I \cdot 0$ has infinitely many solutions, but infinite is not one of them. I was just wondering why docscience was claiming that the current is infinite, which doesn't seem likely. For a piece of wire with zero resistance can be thought of as a smooth surface with zero friction. Something moving on top of it with no net forces applied would move with constant speed. So any current flowing through a zero resistance wire wouldn't change.

Comment: @Phoenix87, I imagine it has to do with the 'paradox' of placing an ideal wire across an ideal voltage source; KVL cannot be satisfied for any value of current through.  If one starts with a resistance $R$ instead, the current $I \rightarrow \infty$ as $R \rightarrow 0$ which I suppose is sometimes loosely stated as "the current would be infinite for an ideal wire".  Of course this neglects the inescapable inductance of an *extended* circuit and so, even with zero resistance and assuming finite initial current, the current is increasing but finite for all $t$.